# soffice fails ONLY when called from RStudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, libreoffice

I'm using RStudio Version 1.3.1093 on a machine with Ubuntu 20.04. My R version is 4.0.3.

There's an unexpected behavior when I call this line of code from within RStudio:

```
system("soffice --headless --convert-to xlsx --outdir files/ files/EGP.xlsb")
```

It fails with the following messages:

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/javaldx: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Warning message:
In system("soffice --headless --convert-to xlsx --outdir files/ files/EGP.xlsb") :
  error in running command
```

The error is exactly the same if I call the "naked" command from RStudio's terminal (`soffice --headless --convert-to xlsx --outdir files/ files/EGP.xlsb`):

```sh
user@machine:~/Right/Path/To/File$ soffice --headless --convert-to xlsx --outdir files/ files/EGP.xlsb
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/javaldx: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**However**, if I do the same call from a terminal,  it just works with no error and produces the expected output:

```sh
user@machine:~/Right/Path/To/File$ soffice --headless --convert-to xlsx --outdir files/ files/EGP.xlsb
convert /home/user/Right/Path/To/File/files/EGP.xlsb -> /home/user/Right/Path/To/File/files/EGP.xlsx using filter : Calc Office Open XML
Overwriting: /home/user/Right/Path/To/File/files/EGP.xlsx
```

I followed advice in [this ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913812/libreoffice-stopped-working-in-ubuntu-17-04), reagarding the need to update `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but the problem does not resolve.

Is RStudio missing the path to find libreoffice libraries, that somehow are clear for the system (as the terminal has no problems finding them)? How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Roah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475685/roah) comment here: [shared library issue with the system function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044342/shared-library-issue-with-the-system-function-in-r)

Adding the `Sys.setenv` bit in the R script worked for me:

```
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/")
system('soffice --convert-to odt table.html')
```